# getting the current number of elements in a matrix to decide when to realloc it

Tags: arrays, c, matrix

I have a matrix that gets `calloced` after program start. I then need to figure out when I need to realloc it (after the array is full). My initial thought was to hold a counter variable inside the struct and increment it after each insert, but i'm thinking there is a better way with using the `sizeof()`? I am using `calloc` so i do not need to use `malloc` and `memset` in conjuction, this means that the indexes that get `calloced` will be set to 0? So i would need to check how many "non zero" elements there are in the array to know when i have to `realloc`. I have wrote a simple test program but i am confused by the bottom `printf` statement that outputs '1'. After the elements are put into this array, they wont be modified in any way, which is why the counter method seems fine to me, but I wanted to test if this worked.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct c {

    char** arr;
};

int main() {

    struct c a;

    a.arr = calloc(40, sizeof(char*));
    
    for (int x = 0; x < 40; ++x) {

        a.arr[x] = calloc(20, sizeof(char));

        a.arr[x] = "lol\0";
    }

    a.arr[30] = "dfsd\0";

    printf("%s\n", a.arr[30]);

    printf("reallocing...\n");

    a.arr = realloc(a.arr, 200 * sizeof(char*));


    if (a.arr == NULL) {

        printf("failed\n");
    }

    for (int x = 40; x < 200; ++x) {

        a.arr[x] = calloc(20, sizeof(char));

        a.arr[x] = "lol\0";
    }


    for (int x = 0; x < 200; ++x) {

        printf("%s\n", a.arr[x]);

    }

    printf("total size: %i\n", sizeof(a.arr) / sizeof(a.arr[0]));
}
```

This should not output one but rather the size of the matrix, since the  sizeof(a.arr[0]) will give you the size of the char type, then divide it into the size of the array in bytes.

Comment: "there is a better way with using the sizeof()" --> No. Use the _hold a counter variable_ approach.

Comment: is there any drawbacks to this approach?

Comment: No.  It's pretty much the accepted and proper way to do it.

Comment: "*this means that the indexes that get calloced will be set to 0*". Put a `int size;` field in the `struct` and keep the size in there. The `realloc` should only be done for the `arr` element so the size will remain.

Comment: I always keep *two* size fields in the struct: the number of elements currently used, and the number of elements currently allocated.  If you keep but a single size fields, that implies you realloc once for each insertion, and that can be significantly inefficient.  With two sizes, you realloc only when used >= allocated, and then you realloc more than you need, by additive (still inefficient for huge numbers of insertions) or multiplicative factors.

Comment: @SteveSummit this was my initial approach, aka MaxSize and CurrentSize as uints

Comment: Yup. `size` vs. `capacity` is generally a good approach.

Comment: You probably know this, but: using `calloc` in that way only works if you know you're never going to store a real value of 0.

Comment: If you do need to have "unused" entries set to 0 for whatever reason, meaning that you're inclined to use `calloc` for the initial allocation, be aware that `realloc` never zeroes contents, so you are going to need an explicit `memset` after `realloc`.

Comment: i wont. only strings will be stored that are 30+ in length

Comment: @SteveSummit will add that, the memset after realloc completely went over my head

Comment: *any drawbacks to this approach?* I said "No", but: I suppose there are "drawbacks" if you do it wrong.  Using `malloc` and `realloc` in this way, at all, is a "low level" technique that may be considered unacceptably error-prone by modern standards.  If you grow your allocation by 1 at a time, or even 10 or 50 at a time, it can be unacceptably inefficient, and it can also fragment memory badly.  On the other hand, if you grow your allocation by multiplying by 2 each time, you can end up overallocating and wasting significant memory, or even running out of memory on a non-VM system.

Comment: Just to complement above comments: `sizeof` is an operator, not a function! Also, the result of its evaluation is the size of a type, which is a purely compile-time thing. Hence, the size is also computed at compile time and doesn't change. That kind-of already gives away that it can't help you with your problem of a run-time dynamic array.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt With VLAs, `sizeof` is computed at run-time.

Comment: Nice one, @chux. I'm more from the C++ side and didn't even think about those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sizeof` is useful to report the size of an *object*.

`*alloc()` returns a pointer to allocated memory.  `sizeof` cannot be used to discern the amount allocated from the returned pointer.  Keep track of memory allocated using auxiliary data.

Perhaps

```
struct c {
  unsigned char **arr;
  size_t rows, columns;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0])` mechanism only works for fixed size arrays within the scope of their original declaration. It cannot be used for determining the size of dynamically allocated arrays, not for arrays passed as a single pointer to a function , stored etc - ie where the array has decayed to a pointer

You have to store the size somewhere yourself